# Analyse TF training speed - how to debug?

Tags: linux, tensorflow

I've trained the same model on 2 installations:
1. iMac (late '13) 3.5Ghz i7 & 32GB ram
2. 1 node in a Debian slurm CPU-cluster with 24cores 2.2Ghz, 64gb ram

Both in TF version 1.0.1 (cpu), both were installed with pip. Training times on the model:
1. iMac: Total Time: 86.92s - 207,42s user 38,82s system 267% CPU 1:32,07
2. Linux: Total Time: 330.66s - real    5m38.478s user  22m14.264s
sys 3m5.964s

Obviously not what I was expecting. How can I search for bottlenecks, or profile, and find out why the Linux setup is so slow?

Comment: There is some documentation on how to gather an op-level timeline from TensorFlow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3850/measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations#t=201703212003481241935). Comparing timelines from the two platforms should give you an idea of what ops are taking longer on the two platforms.

Comment: @mrry thx - on the linux installation the tf.histogram was blocking for a bit and on both the tf.nn.dropout took by far the most time... still very questionable though.. I'll look further